# what is the difference between maven release and maven assemblies plugins?

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

Question says it all, I believe.

Please and thank you

GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) is dedicated to create highly customizable package, such as zip, tgz... files. You define, in a descriptor, the content of the final package (or *assembly*), by including files, directories, dependencies, etc.

The [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) is dedicated to the release *process*, which includes several repetitive manipulations and operations. For example it will do some checks (is there any uncommited changes, some `SNAPSHOT` libraries used and so on), prepare your Source Control Management (CVS, Subversion...), modify the `pom` versions (to get rid of the `-SNAPSHOT`), commit the modified `pom.xml`, etc.
You can have an example of a release process [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html).

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your question about `-SNAPSHOT`. For Maven, a fixed version is linked to a dependency that never changes. For example, two libraries with the same fixed version must be identical. So for example, `foo:bar:1.2.3` is strictly identical to another `foo:bar:1.2.3`

This is **not** necessarily the case for a `-SNAPSHOT` version. The `SNAPSHOT` keyword indicates that the current library is under development. Thus, two versions of `foo:bar:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` and `foo:bar:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` *may* not be identical. A timestamp is used by Maven to check which one is the newest.

So in the normal release process, you have your `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` version, which is not in development anymore. So before releasing this library, you will have to fix the version, i.e. move your `pom.xml` version to `1.2.3`.

This modification can be done by simply modifying the `pom.xml` versions, or it can be managed by the `Maven release plugin` (or also with the [Maven version plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)).

I hope the explanations are now clear regarding this particular aspect of Maven.

Comment: Can you link these together? also how can you remove -SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @garbagecollector I've edited my answer to give more details regarding the SNAPSHOT keyword.